# Memory buildup with dask using function with large intermediates

Tags: memory-leaks, multiprocessing, dask, dask-distributed

I have a general question about dask.compute() that's motivated by a memory buildup I've been experiencing with the function. I'm using dask.compute() and map_partitions() (have tried with dask.distributed and dask.multiprocessing (the later with both with pool=ThreadPool and pool=multiprocessing.pool)) to apply a function that performs a series of operations to chunks of a dask dataframe. The output of the function is a relatively small matrix, but the operations within the function involve really large intermediate matrices. Despite deleting these intermediates, I get a memory buildup over time that eventually causes my kernel to die. This makes me wonder if dask is allocating jobs based only on the expected size of the final output variable, and not on the large calculations within the function, leading to too many jobs being sent and the memory blow-up. Is this possible? Thanks for any insight on what might be going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, consider including some source code to allow others to reproduce your problem. For more information on how to ask a good question, check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of similar issues around (e.g., https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1795 and elsewhere). As in that issue, you may want to run typical python memory monitoring tools on the function first, to see if this is intrinsic behaviour.

Essentially, people have been experiencing memory build-up when creating and deleting a large number of pandas dataframes, and this appears to be a pandas problem unrelated to dask, or maybe even a deeper-level malloc thing. You can do typical things like strongly ensure that you do not keep references live, and you can call `gc.collect()` within your code.